# Appending .webm video chunks using the Media Source API does not work for every video

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video

I have modified this [example](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html) in order to run it with my own videos.
It does not work for any video.

In particular, it **does not start to play** if the video has a duration > 5 sec (I mean the complete video file, not a chunk) what just does not seem reasonable at all and I couldn't find out why this happens.

I get **INVALID_STATE_ERR**: DOM Exception 11  every time I call the method append() and endofstream()

By the way, I tried with a lot of different videos changing parameters and it does not seem to depend on the file size but only on the duration. So that a small part of a video does work.

webkitsourceopen event is fired but not webkitsourceend.

Where could this 'restriction' come from?

Comment: If you find solution, please answer